# Posting data to method in codeigniter, secuirty risk?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been using CodeIgniter, to make a data-entry form with following code.I am sending the as POST to the welcome controller's get_data method.
**Can providing the the action in form like this be vulnerable?Is there any other method?**

```html
<form id='form'  action="<?php echo base_url("welcome/get_data"); ?>" method="POST" style="display:inline;">   
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <label class="col-md-3">First Name :</label><input  class="col-md-3" type="text" name='fname' ></input>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <label class="col-md-3">Middle Name :</label><input class="col-md-3" type="text" name='mname' ></input>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <label class="col-md-3">Last Name :</label><input class="col-md-3" type="text" name='lname' ></input>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <label class="col-md-3">Mobile No. :</label><input  class="col-md-3" type="text" name='Mno' ></input>
  </div>
 </div>  
 <div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <label class="col-md-3">Pin Code : </label><input  class="col-md-3" type="text" name='Pcode' ></input>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <label class="col-md-3">Country : </label><input class="col-md-3" type="text" name='Coun'></input>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <label class="col-md-3">State : </label><input class="col-md-3" type="text" name='St'></input>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <label class="col-md-3">Email : </label><input class="col-md-3" type="text" name='email'></input><br>
  </div>
 </div><br>
   <input class="class-md-3 col-md-offset-4" type="submit" value="Save"/>
 </div>
</form>
```

***Also can I use $this->input>post() to directly insert data in database, is it Mysql injection proof?***

Comment: i am confused what you try to ask but  `$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // returns all POST items with XSS filter`
`$this->input->post(); // returns all POST items without XSS filter`

Comment: $this->input>post() does not gurantee against sql injection for that you have to use active record or query builder class of CI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the form helper class, which contains lots of functions useful for working with forms

[CodeIgniter form helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

do escape your db queries and use the CI built in function `$this->db->escape_str`

[CodeIgniter Db Queries](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html)